# How to give share option through flutter application

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am new to flutter I have gone through the below link to implement share option through my application but that package is not working my flutter version is  0.5.1 and if I add that package in pubspec.yaml I'm getting this error please help me out

```
name: share
description: A new Flutter project.

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  share: ^0.5.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Result::

```
[share] flutter packages get
Running "flutter packages get" in share...
Error on line 11, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.
  share: ^0.5.3
  ^^^^^
pub get failed (65)
exit code 65
```

Here is the link what I refered:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share

PS: Let me know if there is any other way to achieve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Add Package in pubspec.yaml**

**share: ^0.5.3**

```
import 'package:share/share.dart'; 

    void _onShareTap() {
        final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
        Share.share(share,
            sharePositionOrigin: box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
  share: ^0.5.3

Dart file:
import 'package:share/share.dart';

final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
Share.share(BASE64_IMAGE,sharePositionOrigin: box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your package name(first line in `pubspec.yaml`). It's the same as one of the dependency name: `share`. Please rename it to something else and try again.